# Caching with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When using the App Engine datastore for storing entities, what is the applied technique for caching.

I mean, without caching we simply do, something like this:

```
DatastoreService _ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
public void put(String key, String value){
    try {
       Entity e = new Entity(createKey(key)); 
       e.setProperty("key", key);
       e.setProperty("value", value); 
       _ds.put(e); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // handle exception
    }
}
```

So where does caching kicks in? Also how does caching play during get methods.

**Update:**

- Simply put my question would be when to do caching. My basic
  implementation does not do caching at all, just plain put and get to
  the Datastore.
- Should caching be implemented on the lowest level API in my code or in a high level API, in my case, the lowest level API I have is this, the put and get to the Datastore.

Comment: This is too vague to answer. Are you asking "how can we cache that entity"? If so, what's wrong with the documentation?

Comment: Now there are official information about in the [Cloud CDN Documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching)

Answer (score 0):

There are really two kinds of caching to think about in app engine:  memcache for ds entities and edge caching for static assets.  This video from google covers both nicely with specific code examples:

[Google I/O 2012 - Optimizing Your Google App Engine App](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ5_47zy4bY)

For edge caching you can also check out this post by Brandon Wirtz, as the documentation is a bit thin:  [enabling edge caching](http://www.xyhd.tv/2011/11/industry-news/setting-cache-control-headers-in-python-to-take-advantage-of-google-appengines-edgecache/)